# browser javascript keyboard wedge capture from scanner/reader

Tags: javascript, barcode-scanner, webapi, rfid, keyboard-wedge

I'm developing a web page in which the user can use: (in addition to mouse and keyboard)

- a barcode scanner
- an RFID reader

Both of them at client side and work as keyboard wedges that type the code + ENTER

I may configure start/stop chars for the barcode scanner but AFAIK don't have an utility to configure the same for the RFID reader.

What is the best method to capture the individual codes for each device and distinguish them from user input?

I tried installing winusb driver (using zadig) and even though I can open the device I'm at lost with getting the proper setup for receiving the codes from the scanner/reader.

If the were an universal driver to convert an usb device to serial I could use navigator.serial in my code. I couldn't find one yet, any pointers in this direction also welcome.

Thanks in advance
Alex

Comment: Is such an article helpful? [onScan.js - hardware barcode and RFID scanners in web apps](https://a.kabachnik.info/onscan-js.html)

Comment: Hi Kunif. Sorry for the late reply! Yes. For sure that helps a lot! Will give it a try.